# How to install and use Babel and watchers in PhpStorm on Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpstorm, webstorm, babeljs

I've downloaded nodejs (v6.3.0 Current) from https://nodejs.org/en/ and installed it.

I also installed `nodejs` plugin in PhpStorm.

[image]

In my Settings → Languages&Frameworks → Node.js and NPM I can see it settings

[image]

In the PhpStorm's Terminal I'm entering the command:

```
npm install --save-dev babel
```

I see `node_modules` with the `babel.js` in my project

[image]

Also I see it in Settings → Languages&Frameworks → Node.js  → packages

Now I'm changing Npm packgage path from `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` to `myProjectDir/node_modules` (in my case it is `D:\!work\!WEBServers\OpenServer\domains\dev.test.ru\node_modules`).  I don't know why.. Do I need to do that?

I'm creating `js` file with code:

```
let foo = () => console.log('test');
foo();
```

and trying to add a watcher

[image]

But when I'm trying to change something in the file - PhpStorm gives me an error:

> An exception occurred while executing watcher 'Babel'. Watcher has been disabled. Fix it.: 
>   Cannot run program "D:!work!WEBServers\OpenServer\domains\dev.test.ru\node_modules\.bin\babel" (in directory "D:!work!WEBServers\OpenServer\domains\dev.test.ru\src"): 
>   CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid win32 application

---

What am I doing wrong? How to install node, babel and other extensions (gulp, grunt etc) and enable watchers? What settings I should do?

Comment: You are on Windows .. so try `babel.cmd` instead of just `babel` (the later one is for Linux/Mac).

Comment: *"I also installed `nodejs` plugin in the PhpStorm"* AFAIK its bundled by default with latest 2016.2 version so there is nothing to install.

Comment: @LazyOne Don't know about nodejs in phpstrom2016, but you were right about `babel.cmd` indestead of `babel`. It so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @LazyOne in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486453/how-to-install-and-use-babel-and-watchers-in-phpstorm-on-windows#comment64375736_38486453) said: try `babel.cmd` instead of just `babel`.

I Tried it and it worked.

It so simple >_<

---

So, my settings is:

Program - `D:!work!WEBServers\OpenServer\domains\dev.test.ru\node_modules\.bin\babel` (or `$FileParentDir$\node_modules\.bin\babel.cmd` with a macros)

Arguments - `--presets es2015 $FileDir$/test.js --out-file $FileParentDir$/out/test.js`

Working directory - `$FileParentDir$\src`

[image]

---

Or `Arguments` for enable `watcher` to whole folder is:

```
--presets es2015 $FileDir$ -d $FileParentDir$/out
```